# HTTP/REST service spring cloud connector

Tags: spring-cloud, cloud-foundry

Is there any generic implementation of the Spring Cloud REST-API [Connector](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-connectors/) or should I start from a [scratch](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-connectors/spring-cloud-connectors.html)?

The way that apps should interact with the other apps depends on a cloud context, e.g.:

- the `app1` can consume the `app2` REST services without TLS and authorization if there is the [internal routing](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/routes-domains.html#internal-routes) between them
- but otherwise the `app1` has to do it with TLS and authorization

I can imagine that there is a `RestServiceConnector` with a `RestTemplateFactory` that creates a `RestTemplate` with `interceptors` that plug authorization to HTTP connection. All depending on the cloud environment, just like [the RabbitMQ connector](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-connectors/spring-cloud-cloud-foundry-connector.html#_rabbitmq).

Isn't it a common need?

Answer (score 1):

There is an example of how this could be done in a [`spring-boot-cities`](https://github.com/cf-platform-eng/spring-boot-cities#cities-client) sample project. This example is a bit different than what you're suggesting, in that it models the domain provided by the service instead of providing a more generic `RestTemplate` or `WebClient` interface.

This sample does not include knowledge of the Cloud Foundry internal routing feature, as the sample was developed before this was available in CF. That's a nice feature to have, but using the internal routes does require additional configuration of the deployed apps:

> By default, apps cannot communicate with each other on the container
>   network. To allow apps to communicate with each other you must create
>   a network policy.

We would not be interested in including a new feature like this into the core Spring Cloud Connectors project, as we want to limit the scope of the core project to the currently supported services. There is a set of known Connectors extension projects listed in the `Community Extensions` section at the bottom of the [project page](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-connectors/). If you get something working as a stand-alone extension library similar to those already listed, I'd be glad to add your project to that list.